# Format date and time programmatically with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell with the following:

```
=CONCATENATE("This is a date formatted manually: ", 'Master sheet'!B3,"hrs of the following date:", 'Master sheet'!B3, " AND THIS IS IT ")
```

The cell B3 contains a date. The output should be:

```
This is a date formatted manually 2230hrs of the 31/12/2019 AND THIS IS IT
```

I can find ways to format dates with Google Sheets, but how do you actually do it from a formula?

If I save the file as Excel, will it work?

Comment: What's your current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="This is a date formatted manually: "&TEXT('Master sheet'!B3,"hhmm")&
 "hrs of the following date: "&TEXT('Master sheet'!B3, "dd/mm/yyyy")&" AND THIS IS IT"
```

[image: 0]

---

and yes, Excel does support `TEXT` formula:

[image: 0]

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. I realise this was a pretty simple question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere -- admittedly, calc/spreadsheets are not my forte!